# Iphone and javascript screen resolution

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone

Ok, I finished a website a few weeks ago. To make it mobile compliant I was using my smartphone. It was a windows phone, but everything displayed as it should.

Since then I'v got my self a new phone an IPhone. and the javascript I was using on the site isn't working on the IPhone.

I was using to separate style sheets

```
<link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" media="(max-width: 480px)" href="styleSM.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" media="(min-width: 480px)" href="styleS.css">
```

And I think everything is working with those. The problem is when I use this code. I found it somewhere on the internet but it worked.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

<!-- viewport script -->

 var viewportwidth;
 var viewportheight;

 // the more standards compliant browsers (mozilla/netscape/opera/IE7) use window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight

if (typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined')
 {
  viewportwidth = window.innerWidth,
  viewportheight = window.innerHeight
 }

// IE6 in standards compliant mode (i.e. with a valid doctype as the first line in the document)

 else if (typeof document.documentElement != 'undefined'
 && typeof document.documentElement.clientWidth !=
 'undefined' && document.documentElement.clientWidth != 0)
 {
   viewportwidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth,
   viewportheight = document.documentElement.clientHeight
 }

 // older versions of IE

 else
 {
   viewportwidth = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth,
   viewportheight = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight
 }

</script>
```

I then use the variables in a script that dynamically loads content. Like

```
$.each(test, function(i, item){
    if(viewportwidth =< 480){
        do something....
    }
    if(viewportwidth > 480){
        do something else...
    }
});
```

Am I missing something in the javascript that applies to IPhones. Because the script works fine from laptop and my old phone. I really don't know and am not familiar with the phone yet.

basically in my own code I have two choices if viewport width is over 480 set element attributes to something, if = or under 480 set attributes to something else. But they get displayed according to a larger screen size when I use these scripts

Comment: Do you have `<meta name="viewport" conent="width=device-width">` tag in the `<head>` section?

Comment: yes it's there with initial-scale = 1

Comment: I'm pretty sure I need another way of detecting screen width for safari, I just don't know how to go about it.

Comment: Maybe try [window.matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia)

Comment: ok, what it is is that the default screen width for iphones is 980, so the dynamically loaded content is being set with a width for 980. The css must load on window load and be set somewhere else, but on screen onload the width gets treated as 980. I need a way of setting viewport setting viewport width for iphones while keeping the scales the same for all other devices.

Comment: Ok, what I did was add var screenwidth = screen.width; to the test viewport width section. And when using the dynamically loading function, I tested for if(viewportwidth <= 480 || screenwidth <= 480){} and if(viewportwidth > 480 && screenwidth > 480){}. This fixes it, but was wondering if anyone can tell me if there will be any issues with it on other devices.